# Select random rows and update them in the same query?

Tags: mysql

Basically I would like to do the following in one single query. Is it possible?

```
$q = mysql_query('select * from table ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5');
$s;
while($r = mysq_fetch_array($q)){
    $s[i] = $r['id'];
    // Do stuff
}
$u = mysql_query("update table SET lastUpdated = NOW() where id in (".implode(',',$s).")");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use select/update statements for the same table in the same query.

Answer (score 5):

You can just add

```
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```

To the end of your update query

EDIT:

I missed part of the question at first.  The above will work if you *just* need to update 5 random rows.  However, it looks like you need to get 5 random IDs from your table, perform some action with those IDs, and update those rows.  Unfortunately, UPDATE queries can modify data, and SELECT queries can retrieve data, but neither query can do both.  You could probably create some sort of stored procedure to update / select 5 random rows, but that would be more complicated than the 2 queries you currently have

EDIT #2:

If your reason for wanting to do this in the same query is concurrency, you could check out MySQL's [Locking Read](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) feature.

Comment: Then it will update other different random rows! Pus it will still 2 querys

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you needed to capture the IDs as output of the query.  So the answer to your question is "no, you can't do that"